# Simulating an iPhone browser using HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: html, iphone, responsive-design

There are several websites that offer an "iPhone browser emulator". I'm just wondering if there's a way for me to get the same functionality for viewing local html files on my machine.

It seems like basically you would mainly just have to spoof the css "media type". Is that possible using HTML/JS/CSS?

And is there anything other functionality I'm forgetting that would be required for a basic iPhone browser simulator? Obviously discounting all the mobile-only hardware like deviceorientation and gps etc.

Comment: Chrome's dev tools already does all of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a third party website! you can easily do that with Chrome browser:

- F12 to open the developer tools panel
- click the setting gear in the bottom right corner
- in the left panel select Overrides
- "check" the Enable checkbox
- select the desired User Agent
- you might want to change the Device metrics / orientation and enable touch events

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc). Developed by blackberry. 
It's a chrome extension. And you can work with your localfiles